# Perfect URL Checking Regular Expression for MOST URL's

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am working on a project where I need to validate my URL's and stumbled upon the following RegEx pattern;

`/(((http|ftp|https):\/{2})+(([0-9a-z_-]+\.)+(aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mn|mn|mo|mp|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|nom|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ra|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw|arpa)(:[0-9]+)?((\/([~0-9a-zA-Z\#\+\%@\.\/_-]+))?(\?[0-9a-zA-Z\+\%@\/&\[\];=_-]+)?)?))\b/imuS$/` @ https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Which allows me to check URL's that always had a protocol before it (http, https or ftp). I would like to also allow the user to leave out the protocol and it still be valid. How do I do this?

Are there any other RegEx patterns that are better/more accurate that I can use to validate my URL's? Thanks for all answers!

Comment: I used StackOverflow's Q&A button to supply a valuable RegEx expression that can be used for URL checking. I will modify my question to ask for any other possible solutions as well. Thank you @Tushar

Comment: So, You should be always aware of all changes to accepted domain extensions!? ;).

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working a module that validates inputs. One of the validations required me to parse domains ( hostnames ) per:

- [RFC 952](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc952.txt)
- [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-13)
- [Trailing dots in domain names](http://dns-sd.org./TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html)

To validate a domain I took a few steps, one of them was to use the
browser parsing logic by using this cool trick:

```
function parseURI( str ) {
    var a = document.createElement( "a" );

    // If the string doesn't contain a protocol, the browser
    // will default to the current document location.
    a.href = /^(https?:\/\/)/i.test( str ) === false ? ( "http://" + str ) : str;

    // Since I can't overwrite a[property] - return an object I control ( Muahahah ).
    return {
      hash: a.hash,
      hostname: a.hostname,
      href: a.href,
      origin: a.origin,
      pathname: a.pathname,
      port: a.port,
      protocol: a.protocol,
      search: a.search,
      // When parsing the URL by the browser fails, the browser will
      // set the hostname based on the current document.location value.
      valid: a.hostname !== document.location
    }
  }
```

If validating a **hostname | domain** is what you are after, I can share my insights on the topic as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use regex powers in your regex for extension part like this:

```
(aero|asia|arpa|a[c-gil-oq-uwxz]|biz|b[abd-jmnorstv-z]|cat|com|coop|c[acdf-ik-oruvxyz]|
d[ejkmoz]|edu|e[cegr-u]|f[ijkmor]|gov|g[abd-ilmnp-uwy]|h[kmnrtu]|info|int|i[del-oq-t]|
jobs|j[emop]|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikr-vy]|mil|mobi|museum|m[acdeghklnopr-z]|
name|net|nom|n[acefgilopruz]|org|pro|p[ae-hk-nrstwy]|qa|r[easuw]|s[a-eg-ortuvyz]|
tel|travel|t[cdfghj-prtvwz]|u[agksyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw])
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified it to the following so that the user can leave out the protocol;

`/(((http|ftp|https):\/{2})?(([0-9a-z_-]+\.)+(aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mn|mn|mo|mp|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|nom|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ra|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw|arpa)(:[0-9]+)?((\/([~0-9a-zA-Z\#\+\%@\.\/_-]+))?(\?[0-9a-zA-Z\+\%@\/&\[\];=_-]+)?)?))\b$/`

by making the first part (the protocol) optional using the `?` operator.

http://www.regexr.com/ is a great tool to use for testing RegEx patterns and learning about how they work.

Comment: This fails for https://abc.xyz and everything ending with a slash (matches  `http://www.test.com` but not `http://www.test.com/`)